# SQL: find every row with IDs x,y,z where the values exist in no other row

Tags: sql, subquery

**What I have:**
I have two simple tables, with a many-to-many-relation, and thus a table that links them.

**What I want to do**
Table below: I want to find all towns that George and Joe has been in, but no one else has been in (the real database has thousands of entries in both table 1 and 2)

```
TABLE_1               LINK_TABLE             TABLE_2
ID   NAME             ID1   ID2              ID  NAME
1    George           1     1                1   New York
2    Joe              1     2                2   Los Angeles
3    Patrick          1     3                3   London
                      2     1                4   Tokyo
                      2     4                5   Paris 
                      2     3                6   Beijing
                      3     1
                      3     5
                      3     6
```

If I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM LINK_TABLE WHERE ID1 IN (1, 2)
```

I get everything George and Joe have been in, but also the ones that Patrick has been in.

If I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2 
FROM LINK_TABLE 
WHERE ID2 IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID2 
        FROM LINK_TABLE 
        WHERE ID1 IN (1, 2)
    ) AND ID1 NOT IN (1,2)
```

I get the ones that Patrick has been in, and that George and Joe also have been in.

Or I can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2 
FROM LINK_TABLE 
WHERE ID1 IN (1, 2) AND ID2 NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM LINK_TABLE WHERE ID2 IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM LINK_TABLE WHERE ID1 IN (1, 2)
    ) AND ID1 NOT IN (1,2))
```

buuuuuuut, at that point, it starts looking rather weird, and I also fear it's slow.

Is there any more... readable, and hopefully faster way to solve this in an SQL Query? Here's to hoping I'm just being tired after a day's work...

Comment: To clarify: town that have been visited by both George AND Joe (two visits to the town), towns that have been visited by George OR Joe (or both -- could be one visit or two), or towns that have been visited by George XOR Joe (only one visit to the town ever). Any of those could be the explained using the text in the question, but the code would be different depending on which is correct.

Comment: Oh, and a further wrinkle is if it's possible for the George or Joe to have records showing they've visited a town more than once.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the nice re-formatting of my post. Sorry for being sloppy.

I don't need to know which towns have been visited by one and which have been visited by both. All I'm interested is "the towns that Joe and/or George have visited, and that no one else but Joe and/or George have visited.

Also, both for this example and for the real example, the tables won't show that anyone has visited a town more than once. That is, LINK_TABLE cannot have any duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

This might work, but the question isn't fully clear:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2
FROM LINK_TABLE lt1
WHERE ID1 IN (1,2)
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM LINK_TABLE lt2
      WHERE lt2.ID2 = lt1.ID2
          AND l2.ID1 NOT IN (1,2)
    )
```

---

Hmm... you could also try this and it will likely be even faster:

```
SELECT ID2
FROM LINK_TABLE lt1
GROUP BY ID2
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN ID1 NOT IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN ID1     IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Wow. The first one was a "of course, I should've thought of that" (I always get confused when nested queries access the result of the parent query), but the second one was a columbi egg solution. Thanks!

Comment: Fascinating. An interesting note is that

SELECT DISTINCT ID2
FROM LINK_TABLE lt1
WHERE ID1 IN (1,2)
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM LINK_TABLE lt2
      WHERE lt2.ID2 = lt1.ID2
          AND l2.ID1 NOT IN (1,2)
    )

was somewhere between 20 and 50 times faster than

SELECT DISTINCT ID2
FROM LINK_TABLE lt1
WHERE ID1 IN (1,2)
   AND ID2 NOT IN (
      SELECT ID2
      FROM LINK_TABLE lt2
      WHERE lt2.ID2 = lt1.ID2
          AND l2.ID1 NOT IN (1,2)
    )

Comment: @Zimeon That's correct. A quirk of SQL Server is EXISTS() will generally be faster than than IN() ... but this isn't always true of other database platforms, and even for SQL Server there are times the result will surprise you.